Coma pasar datos de varios textbox y los datos de un dataGridview a un reportViewer en c#
Ayuda estoy aprendiendo en C#, necesito su ayuda para poder pasar los datos de varios textbox y los datos de un dataGridView a un reporte  reportViewer en C# de manera correcta . he logrado  generar el reporte bien con los datos del datagridview pero lo malo es que  también repite ciertas filas en blancos con los datos q están en el textbox
ESTA ES LA CLASE:

AQUI SE CARGAN LOS DATOS AL LA LISTA

EL CODIGO EN EL REPORTE

ESTE ES EL REPORTE


Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
